# display a div after click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with one script. I believe it's something simple, unfortunately not that simple for me. 
What I'm trying to do is to display a div (appearing after click). It should happen when you click on "Products". What I have so far is this:

```
   <div id="header">

    <div id="headcont"> 

            <div id="main-menu">
                <a href="#" id="button-products">Products</a>
            </div>

            <div id="products-menu">
                <a href="#">Jackleg units</a>
                <a href="#">Antivandal units</a>
                <a href="#">Storage containers</a>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
    body{

    background-color:#666;

}

#header{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    border-bottom:1px #999 solid;
    padding:15px 0;
    z-index:200;
}

#headcont{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-menu{
    margin-top:55px;
    float:right;
}

#main-menu a{
    display:block;
    width: auto;
    font-size:1.7em;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    color:#eee;
}

#products-menu{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    width:980px;
    display: none;
}

#products-menu a{
    display:block;
    width: auto;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.7em;
    float:left;
    color:#eee;
}
```

- the major thing - jquery:

  ```
  $(function() {
      $('#button-products').on('click', function() {
          $('#products-menu').css("display:","block");
      });
  });
  ```

It's a bit long, so I used jsfiddle to help you understand what I'm trying to do: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/7tbsR/3/). 
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of the colon at the end of the CSS property you are setting:

```
$('#products-menu').css("display:","block");
// remove this -----------------^
```

Remove it and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/4/

(Note that your fiddle didn't have jQuery selected in the panel on the left, so that didn't help either.)

Note also that jQuery offers some methods to display hidden elements, including the plain [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and several [animation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) that fade or slide the hidden item(s) into view. (For your menu [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) is a nice effect: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/7/)

Comment: Great :) That was my next question, the slidedown thing. Great work. thanks :)

Comment: is there any quick way to modify this code http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/7/ to (after first click on 'products') click again and roll up the submenu? so it works both ways? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, just use `.slideToggle()` instead of `.slideDown()`: http://jsfiddle.net/7tbsR/9/ (for more info on `.slideToggle()` or other animation methods see the link I provided in my answer).

Comment: Thank you :) I was trying this but didn't work for me, maybe done something wrong before. Will apply your code now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Works great. I really appreciate all your help @nnnnnn

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#products-submenu").click(function(){

    $("#products-menu").show(); //.fadeIn(600) //Nice Effect

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) will check in a second :)